# Node.js. How can I replace 'return new Promise' with Async Await syntax?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using `Node.js` and [npm mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql). How can I 'get rid' of `return new Promise` here and replace it with `async await` syntax?

```
const config = require('config');
const mysql = require('mysql');

class DatabaseConnection {

static connect(logger) {
    return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {

        const con = mysql.createConnection({
            host: config.db.host,
            user: config.db.user,
            password: config.db.password,
            database: config.db.db,
        });

        con.connect((err) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                logger.debug('Connected!');
                resolve(con);
            }
        });
    }));
  }

}


module.exports = DatabaseConnection;
```

Comment: await is to remove the .then() from a promise, but you still have to use and return a promise

Comment: You may want to switch over to using https://github.com/lukeb-uk/node-promise-mysql if possible (it wraps the `mysql` module)

Comment: async/await doesn't belong in that code section, but the code that consumes this can now use async/wait thanks to it returning a promise.

Answer (score 0):

Since `.connect` uses a callback function, not a `Promise`, you can't. [There are several strategies for wrapping callbacks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)

Answer (score -1):

Just use `util.promisify` to turn the API into a promise, then you can await it:

```
const { promisify } = require("util");

function connect(){

    const con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: config.db.host,
        user: config.db.user,
        password: config.db.password,
        database: config.db.db,
    });

    return promisify(con.connect.bind(con))();
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't need the `await` here; just `return` is enough

Answer (score -1):

You can use this way. Refer to [MDN link for async await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

```
const config = require('config');
const mysql = require('mysql');

class DatabaseConnection {
static connect(logger) {
  
  function getConnect() {
   return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
   const con = mysql.createConnection({
              host: config.db.host,
              user: config.db.user,
              password: config.db.password,
              database: config.db.db,
          });
  }
  async function asyncCall(){
            try
              {
              var status =  await getConnect();

              }catch(err){
              reject('failed');
              }
      }
  
  asyncCall();
}
module.exports = DatabaseConnection;
```